# first class and your advice

Tags: php, class, mysqli

I started learning PHP myself. this is my first class. I need your advice to make my first steps were correct. 
I will take any comments into account. 
 I need your advice about of:

use mysql_connect or mysql_pconnect instead?
 close or not database connection at the end of function? 
 relese resource or not with mysql_free_result?
 Any concepts that i havn't consider.

thanks for any note in advance!

```
                   require_once 'ggc_config.php';
                   class ggc
               {

    //ამ ფუნქციას მიეწოდება მოთხოვნის ტექსტი და ასრულებს მას. აბრუნებს 1, როდესაც   ყველაფერი რიგზეა და აბრუნებს 0 თუ ვერ შესრულდება 
        public static function executequery($querystring)
        {
        $db=mysql_connect (_GGC_HOST_,_GGC_USER_,_GGC_PASSWORD_); 
            if(!$db)   
            {
            die ('Can\'t connect '.mysql_error());  
            }  

        mysql_set_charset('utf8', $db);  
        $tt=mysql_select_db(_GGC_DB_,$db); 

            if (!$tt)            
            {
            echo "Can\'t select DataBase". mysql_error;
            exit;
            }

        $result=mysql_query ($querystring,$db); 
            if (!$result)   
            {
            return 0;
            }
            else
            {
            return 1;
            }
        mysql_free_result($result);  
        mysql_close($db);  
        }
        //end of executequery

     }//End of CLASS
```

Comment: first tip, avoid mysql_ and use mysqli_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not much clear on your codes. Anyway two immediate recommendations:

Put your `mySQL` connection into your `__construct()` method

Second: You should forgot `mysql` extension that is deprecated.

Use instead `mySQLi` or `PDO`, the latter much more better.

Comment: I have declared constants in config.php, I think its more easy to correct text file once VS pass arguments any time you declared class object.

Comment: try to keep your class as independent as possible. If there is any need f arguments, then don't delegate them to other external simple text files, rather, try to structure arguments into your class. If you have any constant outside of your class upon which your class depends, then your class is just a piece of extra work! You MUST incorporate any value, variable, constant into your class for it act independently anywhere. Don't forgot voting if you find mine useful

Comment: thank for your answer, I havn't enought reputation to vote unfortunately!!!!

Comment: thanks, hope it'll come to be useful

Comment: Thanks again!!!! I accepted your answer. Good man!!

Answer (score 0):

I use personally mysqli_connect (note the "i"... original mysql is already deprecated) and I never bother to close the connection (well, it wasn't in the book that I borrowed to learn, so...) and overall, I made simple things to work without any trouble.

Comment: Then why mysql_close method exists?

Comment: Well, you asked and I said what I know. Anyway, I am not using any class to manage connections, I just write it directly in the code. If you see that it works, then why be bothered by doubts?

Comment: Why not use class for common tasks?

Comment: Because I didn't learn to do so in the book and I actually am not a "professional" programmer, but rather someone that works freely for Adsense. So I am not expert in nothing, but rather jack-of-all-trades. That is why my codes have many inconsistencies. But they work and do what I need.

Comment: Thanks anyway for answer. Good man!!!!